# how do i add functionality to each of the buttons?

Tags: javascript

The first part of the code is working correctly, but now that each button appears, how do i add functionality to each of them? currently the only button which does something when pressed is always the last one, the rest do nothing.

Comment: Execute `button.addEventListener(...)` _in_ instead of after the loop.

Comment: Maybe if you didn't use completely arbitrary indentation you'd be able to see the errors in the program flow much more clearly.

Comment: sorry about that i have tidied it up now

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
{

                var output = ""; 
                var data = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
                   for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
                {
                    output  = data[i].title + ' ';
                    var p = document.createElement("p");
                    var div = document.getElementById("response");
                    var textNode = document.createTextNode(output);
                    p.appendChild(textNode);
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                        button.innerHTML = "Download";
                        p.appendChild(button);

                    div.appendChild(p);
                    button.addEventListener ("click", () => 
                    {
                        alert("Test");
                    });
                }
}
```

Comment: Seems like when i do this the first bit of java script no longer does anything

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the below code out side the for loop

```
button.addEventListener ("click", () => 
 { 
    alert("Test");
 } );
```

Keep the above code inside the for loop. So that for each button the event listener will be added.

Comment: the only problem with that is that when i add it into the loop all the the javascript stops working

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this would be to add the callback function to the `onclick` variable of the elements prototype:

```
 function doStuff() {
   var output = "";
   var data = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     output = data[i].title + ' ';
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     var div = document.getElementById("response");
     var textNode = document.createTextNode(output);
     p.appendChild(textNode);
     var button = document.createElement("button");
     button.innerHTML = "Download";

     // Adds the callback function here
     button.onclick = () => {
       // fill in your arrow function here...
         alert("Test");
     };
     p.appendChild(button);
     div.appendChild(p);
   };
 }

doStuff();
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ye0vyy8r/1/) is a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) for dynamically added elements

```js
// sample data
var data = [{
  title: 'one'
}, {
  title: 'two'
},{
  title: 'three'
}];

var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var output = data[i].title + " ";
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var div = document.getElementById("response");
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(output);
  p.appendChild(textNode);
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  // added output to button text for identification
  button.innerHTML = output + " Download";
  p.appendChild(button);
  div.appendChild(p);
}

// Get the parent element, add a click listener
document.getElementById("response").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // e.target is the clicked element!
  // If it was a button
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    // Button found!  Output the identifying data!
    // do other work on click
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML + " Clicked";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="response"></div>

<div id="display">Display</div>
```